# How to create trigger for updating in mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How to Update table1 if the table1 primary key existing in table2. I am using following code but it gives mysql syntax error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_selectoin 
BEFORE UPDATE ON customer 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NEW.customer_sk IN(SELECT quotation_cname FROM quotation) THEN 
 UPDATE customer s JOIN quotation m 
     ON m.quotation_cname = s.customer_sk
    SET s.grade = 2
  WHERE s.customer_sk = NEW.customer_sk; 
END IF;
```

I got the following Error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9

I want to update the customer table grade column if the customer_sk existing in quotation table.Please help me

Comment: Can you add the error message to your question?

Comment: Looks to me you are not using delimiter in the SQL code and you are missed the end statement in your trigger code.